# how to delete partitions from hive table dynamically?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I am new to hive. Can someone please help me with this requirement?

My requirement is to delete partitions dynamically. I had a SQL which results various regions (SQL is below: after `ALTER TABLE FROM`). Now I want to delete the regions (partitioned in my hive table) that are returned by my SQL.

I tried in the below way:

```
ALTER TABLE <TableName> PARTITION(region=tab.region)
FROM
select tab.region from 
(SELECT * from Table1) tab  join
(select filename from  Table2) tab1
on tab1.filename = tab.filename
```

It's throwing the below exception:

```
'1:21:13  [ALTER - 0 row(s), 0.008 secs]  [Error Code: 40000, SQL State: 42000]  Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException 
line 1:77 cannot recognize input near 'tab' '.' 'region' in constant
... 1 statement(s) executed, 0 row(s) affected, exec/fetch time: 0.008/0.000 sec  [0 successful, 0 warnings, 1 errors]
```

Could someone help me please?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Shell-script:***

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/sh

IFS=$'\n' 

#get partitions 
part=`hive -e "select tab.region from (SELECT * from Table1) tab  join (select filename from  Table2) tab1 on tab1.filename = tab.filename"`

for p in $part
do

   partition=`echo $p|cut -d '=' -f2`

   echo Drooping partitions .... $partition

   #drop partitions
   hive -e "ALTER TABLE test_2 DROP PARTITION(region=\"$partition\")"

done
```

***output:***

```
$ ./test
OK
Time taken: 1.343 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
Drooping partitions .... 2016-07-26 15%3A00%3A00
Dropped the partition region=2016-07-26 15%3A00%3A00
OK
Time taken: 2.686 seconds
Drooping partitions .... 2016-07-27
Dropped the partition region=2016-07-27
OK
Time taken: 1.612 seconds
```

**update: ~~> Running shell script from hql** (This is just a POC, make changes according to your req.)
using `! <command> - Executes a shell command from the Hive shell.`

**test_1.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo " This massage is from $0 file"
```

**hive-test.hql:**

```
! echo showing databases... ; 
show databases;

! echo showing tables...;
show tables;

! echo runing shell script...;
! /home/cloudera/test_1.sh
```

**output:**

```
$ hive -v -f hive-test.hql
showing databases...

    show databases
OK
default
retail_edw
sqoop_import
Time taken: 0.997 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
showing tables...

    show tables
OK
scala_departments
scaladepartments
stack
stackover_hive
Time taken: 0.062 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
runing shell script...
 This massage is from /home/cloudera/test_1.sh file
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Using shell script its working. But we are triggering the .hql's using oozie, and the above hql is in middle of large hql file. So I there any possibility if this requirement can be handle in hql? without using Shell script

Comment: @user2531569 I don't think hql can be that dynamic. I'm afraid you will end up with something like: cut your existing hql script in half, let oozie run the first half, let oozie run the shell script, and then let oozie run the last half.

Comment: @user2531569 - I agree with Dennis - [you can run shell script from oozie](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/DG_ShellActionExtension.html) **OR** you can run shell script from `hql` - see my updated answer fro details...